# Update UI with Firebase Observe Data (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a hard time updating the UI on my Swift app while observing a Firebase node. I have a `red_value`, a `green_value`, and a `blue_value` stored in firebase which is being fetched and used to construct a `UIColor` which is then used to update the background color of a button on my UI.  I am successfully fetching the color values, but when i try to update the UI from within the observe closure, the color always turns out to be white and I can't figure out why.

My code can be found below for a better idea of what i am trying to accomplish when loading the view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.charitiesReference.child(charityUsername!).observe(.value) {
            snapshot in
            let values = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

            let redValue = values["red_value"] as! CGFloat
            let greenValue = values["green_value"] as! CGFloat
            let blueValue = values["blue_value"] as! CGFloat
            let charityColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1.0)

            let ripplerFollowers = values["follower_ripplers"] as! [String: Bool]

            if ripplerFollowers["\(self.username!)"] ?? false {
                self.followOrFollowingButton.setTitle("Following", for: .normal)
                //ERROR -> The line below is producing a white background on my button 
                self.followOrFollowingButton.backgroundColor = charityColor
            } else {
                self.followOrFollowingButton.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
                self.followOrFollowingButton.backgroundColor = .clear
            }
        }
    }
```

Update:
    When I change `self.followOrFollowingButton.backgroundColor = charityColor` line to `self.followOrFollowingButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 120, blue: 120, alpha: 1.0)`
it works as intended, which means that something is going on with the `redValue`, `greenValue`, & `blueValue` variables

**Thank you in advance for your help!**

Comment: it could be that update to the UI (the button) must be done on the main thread, not within another thread.

Comment: Tried running a DispatchQueue on the main thread, no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, I had forgotten to divide each of the color values by 255 to put them in the 0.0 - 1.0 range. if the value is above 1.0, it is set to 1.0, which resulted in the white color.

After dividing by 255, it's working like a charm